# preg_match not Working php and java script

Tags: javascript, php, preg-match, scrape

I need to extract a value (id value) from html web page  .
this value is included in JavaScript code.

**my scraper php >**

```php
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
      $handle = fopen($_POST['website_url'], "r");
      if ($handle)
      {
          while (!feof($handle))
          {
              $text .= fread($handle, 128);
          }
          fclose($handle);
      }
      $result = preg_match('(?<=id: ")(.*)(?=",)', $text);

      echo $result;

  }

?>
```

**My javaScript Code is >**

```js
<script type="text/JavaScript">

var geoInstance = gioFinder("geo");
geoInstance.setup({
    id: "126568949", // i need this
    geometre: "triangle",
    type: "html",
    image: 'https://example/126568949.jpg',
});

</script>
```

I need to extract `id` value but `preg_match` not working

Comment: please take note that java != javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the /s wrapping your pattern.

You will also want to set the matches array

```php
$result = preg_match('/(?<=id: ")(.*)(?=",)/', $text, $matches);

echo $matches[0];
```